# rake db rake tasks not working Ruby 2.4.0 & Rails 5.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version, rake, ruby-on-rails-5

In my environment each time I run a rake task (so far only related to active migration) I get three deprecation warnings and then the process seems to kill.

```
➜  job-board-app git:(styles-for-boards-page) ✗ rake db:drop
/Users/jackburum/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/Users/jackburum/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
/Users/jackburum/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:138: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
```

Same thing happens for reset, migrate, etc. Looking for ideas on what I may need to do in order to get the tasks to run successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in Rails 5, you should use `rails task_name` instead of `rake task_name`.

So, use this:

```
rails db:drop
```

Now, about the warning, you are getting the warning because you are using ruby 2.4.0. Checkout the [ruby 2.4.0 release notes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/). Those warnings are  from the activesupport gem and [will go away in Rails 5.0.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27462)

For now, you can just ignore the warning. Upgrade to Rails 5.0.2 as soon as it's released.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer rakib. This was helpful. Thanks for the link also

Answer (score 0):

That are just warnings and it is save to ignore them. You see them, because Rails `5.0.1` is not fully compatible with `Ruby`2.4.0`.

If you are annoyed by this warnings and want to avoid them I would suggest to downgrade Ruby to `2.3.3` temporarily and upgrade again once Rails `5.0.2` is released which fixes this issues.